# Trouble scraping all the follower names from a profile page using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all the follower names from a [profile page](https://rarible.com/artshop) using requests module. The problem is when I run the script below, I get the first 20 names over and over again.

The parameters used in post requests only have two keys and values like `size:20` and `continuation:timestamp`. I tried to use the parameters in the right way but still I get the same results repeatedly.

```
import time
import requests

link = 'https://api-mainnet.rarible.com/marketplace/api/v4/followers'

params = {'user': '0xe744d23107c9c98df5311ff8c1c8637ec3ecf9f3'}
payload = {"size": 20}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://rarible.com',
    'referer': 'https://rarible.com/'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    
    while True:
        res = s.post(link,params=params,json=payload)
        print(s.headers)
        for item in res.json():
            print(item['owner'].get('name',''))

        payload['continuation'] = f"{int(time.time() * 1000)}"
        time.sleep(2)
```

> How can I parse all the follower names from that page using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your next `continuation` value is in `X-CONTINUATION` response header, so this will work when increasing size in payload doesn't:

```py
import requests

link = 'https://api-mainnet.rarible.com/marketplace/api/v4/followers'

params = {'user': '0xe744d23107c9c98df5311ff8c1c8637ec3ecf9f3'}
payload = {"size": 20}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://rarible.com',
    'referer': 'https://rarible.com/'
}

res = requests.post(link, headers=headers, params=params, json=payload)

print(res.headers["X-CONTINUATION"])

while True:
    for item in res.json():
        print(item['owner'].get('name',))
    if not res.headers["X-CONTINUATION"]:
        break
    payload['continuation'] = res.headers["X-CONTINUATION"]
    res = requests.post(link, headers=headers, params=params, json=payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

some api may block you from extracting values more than certain limit and also may show in pages with limits.
For me just increasing the size payload worked with your code.

```
import time
import requests

link = 'https://api-mainnet.rarible.com/marketplace/api/v4/followers'

params = {'user': '0xe744d23107c9c98df5311ff8c1c8637ec3ecf9f3'}
payload = {"size": 10000}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://rarible.com',
    'referer': 'https://rarible.com/'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    res = s.post(link,params=params,json=payload)
    print(len(res.json()))
    for item in res.json():
        print(item['owner'].get('name',''))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution @Sagun Devkota. Although your solution works, I decided to stick with the other answer as it addresses the issue I was facing.